# Observations needed to justify an algebraic passage in proof of a property of $\varphi$ (Totient function)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, totient-function

Let $\varphi$ be the [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be factorized in primes as $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_l^{\alpha_l}$.

I was looking for alternative methods to calculate the value of $\phi$ which **didn't require the Chinese Remainder Theorem**.

I found a very nice proof in "Ireland, Rosen - A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" which use the [Moebius function $\mu$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and the [Moebius Inversion Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)

I've already proved that $$n= \sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d)$$

and this is the proof I'm speaking about.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ [image]

the "problem" is the equality $$ n-\sum_i \frac{n}{p_i} + \sum_{i<j} \frac{n}{p_ip_j} \cdots = n(1-(1/p_1))\cdots(1-(1/p_l))$$

I can't handle it very well and so I can't provide a formal proof of its correctness. I tried to reverse the reasoning and to show that the right side is equal to the left side and then reverse again the reasoning, but I'm submersed with products…

**PLEASE NOTE** I need a proof / reasoning which doesn't use the right side of the equality, in other words I need something which start with something like this $$ n-\sum_i \frac{n}{p_i} + \sum_{i<j} \frac{n}{p_ip_j} \cdots = \ ? $$ ("?" indicates that I don't know what could be the result) and shows how to manipulate the factors to obtain the right side

Comment: Have you already seen Euler's argument for $\varphi$ being multiplicative?

Comment: The $n$ doesn't matter. The expansion of $(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\cdots(1-x_k)$ is clear. True, this uses the right side. If we want to use the left side only, it is a matter of recognizing something familiar.

Comment: @IanMateus $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$ if $(m,n)=1$? I don't think I'll need that here.

Comment: This is actually crucial because it is not hard to show $\varphi(p^k)=p^k(1-p^{-1})$ for $p$ prime. Combine this with FTA and you are set. You can see Euler's proof [here](https://webstorage.worcester.edu/sites/rbisk/web/Number%20Theory/Class%20Notes/3.2%20%20euler%20phi%20function.pdf).

Comment: @IanMateus yeah, but I wanted to follow this reasoning, I spoke about alternative proofs of the properties of totient function, and I've already seen the proof you are describing :) anyway thanks!:)

Comment: @AndréNicolas mmh I think this expansion is the "passage" I need. I'm working out your comment!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm interested in your "something familiar", because I can't see anything familiar :(

Comment: The familiar thing is recalled well by ir7 below. It we really feel like it, we can prove the result easily by induction. Look at the effect of multiplying $(1-x_1)\cdots(1-x_k)$, as expanded on the left, by $1-x_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Think of Vieta formulas (sums), where $\frac{1}{p_i}$ are the "roots". Then set $X=1$.

Vieta: $$X^m - \left(\sum_{i=1}^mx_i\right)X^{m-1} + \left(\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m}x_ix_j\right)X^{m-2}-\ldots = (X-x_1)(X-x_2)\ldots (X-x_m).$$

Comment: so it's a matter of view the "Vieta's formulas" hiding in the sums?

Comment: Yes. Vieta is doing basically what Andre Nicolas is suggesting but with an indeterminate $X$ instead of $1$. Basically, you are adding Vieta SUMS on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

You can show it using a combinatorial argument: the nasty sums come from the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and the product comes from the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Consider the set $S=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}$. Let $A_{r}\subset S$ be the set of numbers $\in S$ divisible by at least $r$ primes in the factorization of $n$. Note (show) that $$|A_{r}|=\sum_{i_1\lt i_2 \lt \ldots \lt i_r}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_r}}\right\rfloor=\sum_{i_1\lt i_2 \lt \ldots \lt i_r}\frac{n}{p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_r}}.$$

How many numbers are coprime to $n$? We will find it using two ways. First, compute all numbers with some common factor to $n$. By the inclusion-exclusion principle, there are exactly

$$n-\varphi(n)=|A_{1}|-|A_{2}|\pm\cdots=\sum_i\frac{n}{p_i}-\sum_{i\lt j}\frac{n}{p_ip_j}\pm\cdots$$

On the other hand, we can compute it in other way. There are $n/p_1$ numbers divisible by $p_1$ and thus $n(1-p_1^{-1})$ numbers coprime to $p_1$. By a similar argument, there are $n(1-p_1^{-1})(1-p_2^{-1})$ numbers coprime to both $p_1$ and $p_2$. Repeating this yields $$\varphi(n)=n-\sum_i\frac{n}{p_i}+\sum_{i\lt j}\frac{n}{p_ip_j}\mp\cdots=n(1-p_1^{-1})(1-p_2^{-1})\cdots$$

Comment: Seems a very interesting proof, but I didn't understand what kind of sets you are considering to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle. So, can can you expand a little that passage?

Comment: @RicPed the first sum is $\sum n/p_i$, with $p_i\mid n$. It represents the number of divisibles by $p_1, p_2,\ldots$. The second sum is the number of divisibles by $p_1p_2, p_2p_3, \ldots$ and so on. It should be $\lfloor n/p_ip_jp_k\cdots\rfloor$ originally, but as $n$ is divisible by them, it is a integer, so we can drop the floors.

Comment: @RicPed I edited the answer to make the sets explicit.